# Maximum row sums after removing column at each step

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, optimization, summation

I have an `n*n` symmetric matrix, with non-negative values.
I want to remove k rows, those with the minimum row-wise sums.

Since the matrix is symmetric, after every row removal, the corresponding column will be removed too.

So, the row-wise sums will be **recalculated** after every removal.

Can anyone recommend a relevant optimization algorithm?

I thought to solve it as a *maximum clique problem*, with the weight of each node being the "row-wise sum", but I think that this does not solve the problem.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720737/from-an-interview-removing-rows-and-columns-in-an-n%C3%97n-matrix-to-maximize-the-su) what you are looking for?

Comment: @VHarisop not really, my matrix is symmetric, with only non-negative values, and after every step a column is removed, so the problem is not the same, unless I can not anticipate the equivalence...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let $c_{i,j}$ be the value of the $(i,j)$ entry in the matrix. Let binary variable $x_i$ indicate whether row $i$ and column $i$ are removed.  Let binary variable $y_{i,j}$ indicate whether entry $(i,j)$ is removed.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_{i,j} c_{i,j}(1-y_{i,j})$ subject to:
\begin{align}
\sum_i x_i &=k\\
x_i&\le y_{i,j}\\
x_i&\le y_{j,i}
\end{align}
The first constraint forces exactly $k$ rows (and the same columns) to be removed. If $x_i=1$, the second constraint forces all row $i$ entries to be removed and the third constraint forces all column $i$ entries to be removed.

Equivalently, this is a maximum edge-weighted $(n-k)$-clique problem, with edge weights $c_{i,j}$.

Comment: Thanks @Rob Pratt! Nice and compact solution. Out of curiosity, in the maximum edge weighted clique problem, the nodes should be adjacent. Is this necessary in this specific problem?

Comment: The clique formulation selects a set of $n-k$ nodes to survive.  For each pair $(i,j)$ of surviving nodes, the matrix entry contributes $c_{i,j}$ to the objective. The underlying input graph here is complete, with an edge for every pair of nodes.

Comment: Great, thanks! BTW, I was considering removing `c_ij * 1 ` from the maximization formula since it is a constant...

Comment: Yes, it would be equivalent to minimize $\sum_{i,j} c_{i,j} y_{i,j}$.